# How to check if a row exists in c#

Tags: c#

This is my first post.I am not to familiar with c#.I have the following code that adds or updates a table as follows.

```
context.Configuration.AddOrUpdate(
    c =>  c.ClientSiteId,
    new List.Configuration
    {
        ClientSiteId = 0,
        APIUserName = "Name",                   
        APIPassword = "Password"
    });
```

How do i tell the above to check if the clientsiteid of 0 exists  it shouldn't update, if there is no clientsiteid of 0 then it should add.

I know you can use `Any()`, I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: *"if the item exists it shouldnt update,if there is no item then it should update"*, you mean you just want to add?

Comment: from `AddOrUpdate`, can we infer that you're using Entity Framework?

Comment: "exits" and "exists" are two really different things. When I opened this question I was expecting checks on whether a launched program had exited.

Comment: @Bharadwaj it currently updates the record based on clientsiteID=0 if there is no client site id of 0 then it will update.i want to check if the clientSiteID of 0 already exists then it shouldnt do any updates

Comment: @Bharadwaj further: "if there is no item then it should update." - if there is no item, it **can't** "update"; update has a very specific meaning...

Comment: @Nyerguds sorry typo

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep, that's what confused me what exactly is required here.

Comment: @john having "0" in `clientSiteID` is not good practice.

Comment: Please avoid *"This is my first post.I am not to familiar with ..."*, because it doesn't help anyone to answer your question, and is pure noise. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) on Meta StackExchange.

Comment: Is it `EntityFramework` or `nHibernate` or maybe something else? We are not magicians, tag your question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use `Add`, not `AddOrUpdate`. The other part, of course, is what we need to do if it already exists. The *simplest* solution there is to ensure that a suitable unique constraint exists, and simply let it explode if you try to duplicate. A more elegant ORM-based approach might be to try to *find* the item, and if it doesn't exist - add it; i.e.

```
var newObj =  new List.Configuration
{
    ClientSiteId = 0,
    APIUserName = "Name",                   
    APIPassword = "Password"
}
// ...
var item = dbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClientSiteId == newObj.ClientSiteId);
if(item == null) {
    dbSet.Add(newObj);
} else {
    // do something graceful, like tell the user
}
```

Note that because of race conditions, this kind of check should still be paired with a DB-level constraint, if the uniqueness matters.

You probably *could* use `Any` in place of the `SingleOrDefault`, but... up to you, really; for example:

```
if(!dbSet.Any(x => x.ClientSiteId == newObj.ClientSiteId)) {
    // add
} else {
    // graceful error
}
```

but ultimately, getting a `null` from `SingleOrDefault` is about as cheap as `Any`, and in the "graceful error" case you might want to give details like:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException(
    $"New configuration conflicts with {item.ClientSiteId} '{item.APIUserName}'");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd run FirstOrDefault(c =>  c.ClientSiteId) to get the DB object with that ID, if it exists then the object will be populated and can be modified, if it doesn't exist then the default values will be returned, at which point you can change them and then commit.